# Relative Velocity and closest approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A container ship is travelling at a speed 15 knots in SE direction. It is a distance of 20 nautical miles due north of a small pilot boat which can travel at a speed 25 knots.

a. In what direction must the pilot boat steer in order to meet the container ship?
b. How long will it take the pilot boat to reach the container ship?

NB: sailors measure distances in nautical miles which are slightly longer than land miles. They measure speeds in knots. 1 knot is 1 nautical mile per hour.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  draw a picture.  Label the current locations of the ships and the direction of travel of he container ship.  If the container ship starts at $(0,0)$, its position at time $t$ is $(\frac {15t}{\sqrt 2},\frac {15t}{\sqrt 2})$.  The pilot boat starts at $(0,-20)$.  Write an equation that gives the pilot boat position as a function of time and heading, then match it up with the container ship position.

The difference between nautical miles and statute miles is immaterial because the speeds and distances are measured in consistent units.  If they were feet it wouldn't matter, either.